# OpenCV and Mat::forEach operator not working in full image

Tags: opencv3.0

I am trying to segment a depth image, so that values of depth between limits (low and high) remain the same, and values outside limits are set to 0.
To accomplish this I am trying to use the forEach method in OpenCV 3, to speed up the operation using all the available cores of the CPU.

Implementing the function this way, it works:

```
void Filter_Image(cv::Mat &img, int low, int high)
{   
    for (uint8_t &p : cv::Mat_<uint8_t>(img)) 
    {
        if(((p > low) && (p < high)) == false)
            p = 0;
    }
}
```

However, when I try to use the lambda expression, I only get correct results in one vertical third of the image  (if you  splitted the image in 3 columns, I only get the first left column well segmented). The code is as follows:

```
void Filter_Image(cv::Mat &img, int low, int high)
{   
    img.forEach<uint8_t>([&](uint8_t &p, const int * position) -> void {
        if(((p > low) && (p < high)) == false)
            p = 0;
    });
}
```

The functions are called from this piece of code (simplified for testing):

```
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>      
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp> 
#include <iostream> 
#include "config_parser.h"
#include "background_substractor.h"
#include "object_tracker.h"
#include "roi_processing.h"
#include "filtering_functions.h"

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ 
    Mat opencv_frame;       
    namedWindow("Input Video");

    //parse config
    VIDEO_CONFIG videoConfig;
    BACK_SUBS_CONFIG backSubsConfig;
    TRACKER_CONFIG trackerConfig;
    ROI_CONFIG roiConfig;
    FILTERING_DATA filteringData;
    Parse_Config("../Config/ConfigDepthImage.json", videoConfig, backSubsConfig, trackerConfig, filteringData, roiConfig);
    Display_Config(videoConfig, backSubsConfig, trackerConfig, filteringData, roiConfig);

    VideoCapture videoInput(videoConfig.path.c_str());
    if (!videoInput.isOpened())
    {
        std::cout<<"Could not open reference video"<<std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    while (1)
    {
        videoInput >> opencv_frame;
        if(opencv_frame.empty())
        {
            std::cout<<"Empty frame"<<std::endl;
            destroyWindow("Input Video");
            destroyWindow("Filtered Video");
            break;  
        }
        Filter_Image(opencv_frame, filteringData.min, filteringData.max);
        //show video
        imshow("Input Video", opencv_frame);
        waitKey((1.0/videoConfig.fps)*1000);    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The difference in results can be observed in the displayed images:
This is the good one:
[image: good segmentation]

And this is the bad result in the same conditions using forEach:

[image]

I cannot see the error or the difference between the two functions. The type of the image is CV_8UC1.
Could anyone provide a clue?
Thank yo all very much in advance.

Comment: This works ok for me. Please show how you call these functions. See how to do a [mcve]

Comment: Edited the question, with the main program and the result images